# Send invitations Via Linkedin using jquery or react or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linkedin-api

I want to send an invitation via Linkedin from my site with some token code from my site. For that I tried that code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

        function invite() {
        var url = '/people/~/mailbox',
            body = {
            recipients: {
              values: [{
                person: {
                  _path: '/people/email=dineshsharma.developer@gmail.com',
                  'first-name':'Dinesh',
                  'last-name':'Sharma'
                 }
              }]
            },
            subject: 'Invitation to connect.',
            body: 'Say yes!',
            'item-content':{
                 'invitation-request':{
                     'connect-type':'friend'
                 }
            }
            };
        IN.API.Raw()
            .url(url)
            .method("POST")
            .body(JSON.stringify(body))
            .result(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: '8145jr5s78ow'
        onLoad: invite
        authorize: true
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But its gave me that error in console:-

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'credentials'
>   of null

I also tried with node for node below is the link form where I tried :-

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkedin-auto-connect
```

But When I run this its showing me this error message

> error:   Request failed with status code 303

If any one have any idea please help me , Thank you in advance